# Android: Displaying WhiteSpace When Closing Soft Keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have a layout which contains a ListView and a EditText below the ListView which is used for searching in list view. The problem is that when i close the soft keyboard after a search, it gives a jerk and shows white space while closing the soft keyboard. I have tried adjustPan, but it moves the whole layout up.

[image]

Comment: have you test on device or emulator ?

Comment: I had a [same issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20559963/empty-space-when-i-return-to-activity-soft-keyboard-forced), a white space when the soft keyboard closed. You should try to make a `Handler` with `postDelayed` method before doing something. Also did you try with `adjustResize` instead of `adjustPan`?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void hideKeyboard(Context context,View v)
    {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(
                  Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);

    }
```

Hope this helps!