# Android - Slow to hide the soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-softkeyboard, android-cardview

I have a problem, the keyboard is hidden very slow and has a delay to hide (approx 1 second).

**I have another application, which uses fragments, normal work, the keyboard is hidden fast.**

**I have done some tests:**

1 - when there is something behind the keyboard (cardview or another control like imageview), it freezes and lag for **1 second before hiding**..

2 - when there is nothing behind (empty layout), **hide quickly**.

I leave two **screenshots**:

Normal Keyboard

[image: Normal Keyboard]

Here, the keyboard is hidden, but look at the screen, is not refreshing !!!

[image: Hidden keyboard]

After one second the screen is refreshed correctly and the keyboard is hidden, but why this happens?

thanks !!!

Comment: Did you get any solution for this ?

Comment: This is probably related to an old issue I had. I'm not able to reproduce it now but I thought it was because I used too many things on the same fragment (searchview, custom viewpager, etc). [Bhavesh posted an answer which apparently should work](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27038872/2668136), I hope this will help you as well.

Answer (score 1):

Add following line in AndroidManifest.xml

```
        <activity
        android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
         >
```

Comment: I also try this solution not working for me.i have the same issue..help me