# How to make a Custom View(EditText) on the actionbar automatically selected?

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, android-edittext

Currently I am making an app that has an EditText on the action bar. I found out how to put a custom view on an actionbar from the following link: [How to set a custom view in actionbar in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27670684/how-to-set-a-custom-view-in-actionbar-in-android).
I used the getSupportActionBar to load an EditText onto the action bar.

```
getSupportActionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_view);
```

It loads an xml file called actionbar_view.xml. The code for that xml file follows below.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/searchfield"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:hint="Search for some app" >

</EditText>
```

The problem is that unlike all normal EditTexts placed on the area below an actionbar the edit text on the actionbar is not automatically selected. Is there a way to make this Edit Text on the action bar automatically selected?

By the way, I did take a look at the following  link, [How to focus and show soft keyboard when a EditText is shown in action bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12875963/how-to-focus-and-show-soft-keyboard-when-a-edittext-is-shown-in-action-bar) Unfortunately I tried to understand the solution and apply to my code but the edit text was still not automatically selected. I am still pretty new to stack overflow, so in case I am not providing enough information/code to solve my problem please tell me in the comments. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, so after doing some research I found a method called request focus. Request Focus will request focus for the editText, BUT I also needed to add two more lines of code. These two lines of code will pop up the keyboard when the editText is selected. Problem solved! Below is how I requested focus for an edit text on an actionbar.

```
searchq.requestFocus();
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.showSoftInput(searchq, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well there is an alternative to make a custom view as you want .. You don't have to do it in the `ActionBar` You can Just Hide The `ActionBar` and make your own view In the `xml` because you might face some limitiations when using in `actionbar`..
Hope it might help...